# Why does the Cauchy Integral Formula hold for when $\gamma$ is not a circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I know how to prove that:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{f(w)}{w-z}\,dw$$

Where $\gamma$ is a positive-oriented circle in some subset $U\subset\Bbb C$ such that $f$ is holomorphic on $U$ and continuous on $\overline{U}$.

The proof relies on:

$$\oint_\gamma\frac{1}{w-z}\,dw=2\pi i$$

When $z$ is the centre of $\gamma$.

However, what does one do when $z$ is *not* the centre of $\gamma$, or *even when $\gamma$ is not a circle*? We can't use the Cauchy Integral Theorem to show the two line integrals are equivalent, as $(w-z)^{-1}$ is not holomorphic, but the Cauchy Formula assumes that that line integral is always equal to $2\pi i$ anyway...

Why?

Note: I know little complex analysis, and am trying to understand the proofs of the Cauchy Integral formulae/theorems from first principles, so please don't involve the residue theorem in an answer as the residue theorem itself relies on the Cauchy Integral Formula (I think).

Comment: Use the fact that the line integral of a holomorphic function does not change when you homotopically deform the curve.

Comment: This is a topological point (I think) and I would have no idea how to prove that @TedShifrin

Comment: Green's Theorem? Regardless, it's argued in every complex analysis text.

Comment: I know Green's Theorem and its proof... oh! Thank you! Where does "homotopy" come into it? @TedShifrin

Comment: You can prove that the integral depends only on $\gamma$ up to homotopy (provided $f$ stays in holomorphic in its interior, and you probably want to keep $\gamma$ in the $C^1$ category), or you can use Green's theorem (or even the more general Stokes' theorem) to prove it. Unfortunately, there's no free lunch here; it either requires some nontrivial topology or nontrivial analysis.

Comment: @anomaly I know Green's theorem but saw no mention of "homotopy" in the proof or the theorem statement

Comment: If you're being fancy, the $1$-form $g(z)\,dz$ is closed and the integrals of the pullback by homotopic maps of closed forms are equal. Intuitively, watching the homotopy gives you a region to which you do apply Green's Theorem. Every complex analysis text I have taught out of discusses the very basics of homotopic curves in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Depends on the definition of holomorphic function and theorems available. Green's Theorem wants the partial derivatives to be continuous which you might or might not have at your disposal depending on the flow of the "every complex analysis text".

Comment: @TedShifrin After some thought, I believe your argument is as follows: If you can continuously change $\gamma_1$ into $\gamma_2$ and the regions they enclose $D_1,D_2$ have the same area, then their line integrals are the same because the double integral of partial derivatives $\iint_{D_1}=\iint_{D_2}$ implies the line integrals are the same by Green's Theorem. Is this correct?

Comment: @FShrike: I mean that if you want to extend the result from a circle to a more general curve, you're either going to have to use a bit of nontrivial topology or use Green's theorem on that curve--- and in the latter case, you're probably going to have to go through some tedious and complicated process of approximating smooth (or $C^1$, etc.) curves by piecewise-linear curves. If you know that the integral in question is integer-valued, then its continuity in $\gamma$ (under a suitable topology) is enough; but even that takes a bit of work.

Comment: @anomaly Oh - so there's no proof that's particularly accessible to a fresh complex analysis student? Where might I find a link to one, anyway?

Comment: There are definitely proofs available, but they all take a bit of work. The easiest way to the invariance of $\int_\gamma f$ under a suitable homotopy of $\gamma$ is by applying Stokes' theorem to a suitable $3$-form, but that's hardly from scratch. Standard texts like Ahlfors or Rudin have accessible proofs, but they take most of a chapter to develop properly. It's a surprisingly complicated result just because of the generality of how closed curves work in $\mathbb{C}$. (It's close to the Jordan curve theorem, which is a pain to prove without, e.g., algebraic topology and Alexander duality).

Comment: Undergraduate texts like Churchill (which is very popular) cover this as well, without anything too fancy.  FShrike, look at the region *between* the two curves. In fact, in your case you can't look at the entire region inside either curve, because $z$ is in there and the function fails to be holomorphic at $z$.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at Cartan's complex analysis text. Chapter 2 contains all the information you need, and everything is treated in sufficient generality (and the idea of homotopy is also covered quite a bit)

Comment: @TedShifrin I have come back to this question as I have learnt more in the meantime. I’ve seen a formal proof for the homotopic invariance of holomorphic functions, but I realise that $\frac{1}{w-z}$ indeed fails to be holomorphic on the interior. How does one attack the region between some $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, as you mentioned in your comment? If I tried to do this with a double area integral, would I be wasting my time? If it’s not too much to ask, I might also add: under what conditions of $f$, for $f$ meromorphic, are the contour integrals invariant with homotopy?

Comment: You just apply Green's Theorem on the region between the two curves. The point is that a holomorphic function in that region yields a zero integrand (that's the C-R. equations). A meromorphic function that is *holomorphic* on this region is fine — but you can't have any poles in that region.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your time Sir! Such details are not easy to find without this forum